# Cannot find unallocated free space in ubuntu 18.04 installer

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have created a 25 GB unallocated free space for installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I also have Windows 10 installed. But in the Ubuntu installer, it is not showing me the free space. Please help me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the third picture in the suggested link above. Select SOMETHING ELSE, the third choice, and send us a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwd1.jpg  25GB unallocated freespace is not showing

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same situation, I have 38 gb unallocated (thank you w10 paging)
but ubuntu sees only 8.2 gb (min required 8.6gb) it does not prompt me to any kind of selection during the installation, just keyboard and wifi, any suggestion?
I really don't feel that this question as a duplicate, 
the answers linked are not useful or at least don't offer a clear solution